# Use internationalization to set the title bar value on Xamarin.Android with the MvvmCross framework

Tags: android, internationalization, xamarin, mvvmcross, titlebar

All is in the title : I want to know if it's possible to set the title bar value of my Xamarin.Android activity using the internationalization of MvvmCross, namely MvxLang.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no axml entry for the Title - so you have to do this in code.

However, you can set the title from the `OnCreate` if you want to - you can access the text using your ViewModel - e.g. something like `Title = ((BaseViewModel)ViewModel).TextSource.GetText("PageTitle");`